# Returning an Double/Integer from a Method in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make code that takes a set of numbers in, runs them through the quadratic formula and returns the answer that is then printed.

P.S. I'm new to java, doing this to learn.

```
Scanner firstCoeff = new Scanner(System.in);
int ax = firstCoeff.nextInt();
firstCoeff.close();
Scanner secCoeff = new Scanner(System.in);
int bx = secCoeff.nextInt();
secCoeff.close();
Scanner finConstant = new Scanner(System.in);
int c = finConstant.nextInt();

Quadratic_Formula work = new Quadratic_Formula();
work.posquadForm(ax, bx, c);
work.negquadForm(ax, bx, c);

System.out.println("Your answer is" + work.posquadForm() +"or" + work.negquadForm() +".");
```

Here is the formula class:

```
public class Quadratic_Formula {
public double posquadForm(int ax, int bx, int c) {
    int b;
    b = (bx);
    int a;
    a = (ax);

    double posanswer;
    posanswer = ((-b) - Math.sqrt((b^2) + ((-4) * a * c)) / (2 * a));
    return posanswer;
}
public double negquadForm(int ax, int bx, int c) {
    int b;
    b = (bx);
    int a;
    a = (ax);

    double neganswer;
    neganswer = ((-b) + Math.sqrt((b^2) + ((-4) * a * c)) / (2 * a));
    return neganswer;
}
```

Comment: "posquadForm() in Quadratic_Formula cannot be applied to: *List of integers passed into the method". According to Idea.

Comment: `public double posquadForm(int ax, int bx, int c)` takes in 3 integers, but when you call `System.out.println("Your answer is" + work.posquadForm() +"or" + work.negquadForm() +".");`, you are not passing in any integers.

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
Quadratic_Formula work = new Quadratic_Formula();
double posAnswer = work.posquadForm(ax, bx, c);
double negAnswer = work.negquadForm(ax, bx, c);

System.out.println("Your answer is" +posAnswer  +"or" + negAnswer  +".");
```

Your functions `posquadForm` & `negquadForm` have already computed the answers, you just need to store them in variables and print them out?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is declared as such:

```
public double posquadForm(int ax, int bx, int c) {
```

So just pass in those variables...

```
int valueForAx = 2;
int valueForBx = 3;
int valueForC = 4;
System.out.println("Your answer is " + work.posquadForm(valueForAx, valueForBx, valueForC));
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note, instead of:

```
int b;
b = (bx);
int a;
a = (ax);
```

you just use:

```
int b = bx;
int a = ax;
```

And the opposite of Alex K's answer is to not take any parameters, just deal with ax, bx and c as globals (assuming the quad formula class is an inner class).

```
public double posquadForm() {

    double posanswer;
    posanswer = ((-bx) - Math.sqrt((bx^2) + ((-4) * ax * c)) / (2 * ax));
    return posanswer;
}
```